# Which words are appearing together quite often in Dataset?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pandas

I have a Dataset something like,

```
S.No       Country            Budget                      Technology

 1     Israel                   100                 javascript,css,html 
 2     United States            450               python,css3,database 
 3     Australia                300               javascript,angular,node 
 4     Russia                   250               javascript,php,python 
 5     Israel                   700                    python, php
 .       .                       .                          .
 .       .                       .                          .
```

I have tokenized the Technology column and counted the technology which is most popular. I have computed countries with highest budgets as well.

Now, I'm trying to find the combinations of Technologies.. Like, Javascript is being used which what technologies more often? Since I tokenized the dataset and split it, I'm not been able to re-combine and use it for such purpose.

I want to compute, Javascript is being used more often with css3 most often then with html then with node, etc etc (Just an example). Any approach to do it? 
Also, I have to see what countries are using which technologies more often? Like, JavaScript is being used more in Australia, Israel, Russia while Python is being used in United States. This should be computed based on counts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC:
This tells you other tech used with and without js

```
df.Technology.str.get_dummies(',').groupby('javascript').sum()

             php  angular  css  css3  database  html  node  php  python
javascript                                                             
1              0        1    1     0         0     1     1    1       1
0              1        0    0     1         1     0     0    0       2
```

Comment: Thanks! 
How do I sort this? As in to print the top ones at first. Dataset is quite huge.

Comment: `df.Technology.str.get_dummies(',').groupby('javascript').sum().loc[1].sort_values(ascending=False)`

Answer (score 1):

I tried this and it works. You just need to check if the string contains a particular set of characters. This will give you which countries are using a particular technology. Please comment what more you need, and I'll help you with it. :

```
from collections import Counter
df['Technology'] = df['Technology'].apply(lambda x: Counter(x.split(',')))
print(df['Technology'])
>>> df['Technology']
0        {u'javascript': 1, u'html': 1, u'css': 1}
1    {u'node': 1, u'javascript': 1, u'angular': 1}
2      {u'python': 1, u'javascript': 1, u'php': 1}
```

Comment: Thanks! 
I'm willing to share my Kaggle Dataset along with my code written so far. Could we collaborate on the matter to get more insights from data? It's an interesting dataset.

Comment: @arjunbhasin I don't have the time and luxury to take part in Kaggle competitions as of now. If you need any help from this community, I can help you out as best as I can.

Comment: That's okay!
I have to compute frequency of technologies used with Javascript. Like, how often php is appearing in the same column as Jvaascript. That develops a score for php, similarly for every technology mentioned. How do I do it?

Comment: Please upvote, select an answer and close the question if your requirement is sufficed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dictionary. Iterate over your dataset checking if javascript is mentioned. When so, for every tech increment it's counter. As a result, you will have a dictionary of technologies mentioned with javascript with their frequencies.